# Logic Apps : Move Email

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I am trying to move an email to a different folder however when I use an action; it is asking me for the "Message-Id" how can I find the email's message Id.

Comment: why there is a negative vote on this ? is asking the question is not allowed here Huh!

Answer (score 1):

`message-id` is a unique identifier of the message. For moving a message to a particular folder, you need a unique identifier which is `message-id` in this case.

In our logic Apps,`Move Email` is the ***Action*** which you are going to perform. So you obviously need a ***trigger*** to make this ***action*** to work. You will get the `message-id` from the trigger which you don't need to worry about it.

For an instance, I have a logic App which triggers whenever a new Email received to me then perform the action of moving that message to a particular folder.

[image]

Here I can get the message id from the input, which is a ***trigger*** `(When a new email arrives)`

Comment: I want to send email to a particular folder. So do I need two logic apps then? one for sending the email and second where the trigger is "When a new email arrives"?

Comment: @BillyBowBow Actually, Logic Apps is an Azure Service. see the doc first https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-overview
You need a single Logic App, in which you have to define two task 1. Creating a Trigger to set when an Email is received to you.2. Move that message to that particular folder

Comment: I am myself sending the email to my email account. I want to send it to a particular folder. Hence I asked if I would need two logic apps then; one to send the email and other to move ?

Comment: Yes you can do that also with two logic apps one for sending emails while other will trigger when email received and move to that folder

Comment: @BillyBowBow Is the above solutions helped you. Then mark it answer so that it would helpful for other community members